# How did DnD 3.0 barbarian optimization work?

Tags: optimization, dnd-3e, history-of-gaming

I started thinking about this after my wife demanded that I optimize a 3.0 barbarian character. I never paid much attention to martial optimization back in 3.0 though, so I don't know how to think about it. And unfortunately, it looks like most contemporaneous records were lost in the various forum collapses.

What were the major themes in optimizing a Barbarian-like character in 3.0 (not 3.5)? Were there a few specific builds generally recognizable as archetypal optimizations, or was it a wide open field?

I'm interested in any specific builds which are relevant to this answer, but I am most interested in understanding how optimizers were thinking then.

Comment: I think asking this as "where do I start optimizing a D&D 3.0 barbarian" is answerable, "what was the thought process of optimizers in the days of yore" isn't. We do top-level-guidance op questions, see https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/are-character-build-or-optimization-questions-on-topic on how to do that well.